# (Scalding) groupBy foldLeft using the group by value in the fold

Tags: scalding

Have data like :

```
pid  recom-pid
1   1
1   2
1   3
2   1
2   2
2   4
2   5
```

Need to make it :

```
pid, recommendations
1    2,3
2    1,4,5
```

Meaning ignore self from the 2nd column, and make the rest in to a comma separated string. Its tab separated data

Tried variations of, but not sure how to refer to productId in the foldLeft

```
.groupBy('productId) {     
  _.foldLeft(('prodReco) -> 'prodsR)("") {
    (s: String, s2: String) =>
      {
        println(" s " + s + ", s2 :" + s2 + "; pid :" + productId + ".")
        if (productId.equals(s2)) {
          s
        } else {
          s + "," + s2;
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Using scala 2.10 with scalding 0.10.0 and cascading 2.5.3. Need a scalding answer. I know how to manipulate the data in scala. I'm just wondering how to get hold of the columns during group by in scalding and use them to conditionally do a fold left or other means to get the filtered output.

For a full working sample see https://github.com/tgkprog/scaldingEx2/tree/master/Q1

Comment: why not use filer to remove the self pairs and then group by the id ?

Comment: Yes that works, just wanted something in scalding groupBy so can filter out in the same phase

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `groupBy` and then `foldLeft`, use just `foldLeft`.
Here is a solution using scala collections but it should works using [scalading as well](https://github.com/twitter/scalding/wiki/Type-safe-api-reference#foldleft-and-fold):

```scala
val source = List((1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,2), (2,4), (2,5))                                                                                
source.foldLeft(Map[Int, List[Int]]())((m,e) =>                                
  if (e._1 == e._2) m else m + (e._1 -> (e._2 :: m.getOrElse(e._1, List()))))
```

Comment: foldLeft is not a member of Pipe. Looks like in the docs its there as a heading but is under reducers

Answer (score 1):

Just a `groupBy` and a `map` should be enough to accomplish what you want.

```
// Input data formatted as a list of tuples.
val tt = Seq((1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 4), (2, 5))

tt
  .groupBy(_._1) // Map(2 -> List((2, 1), ...), 1 -> List((1, 1), ...))
  .toSeq // for easier mapping
  .map({
    case (pid, recomPids) => {
      val pids = recomPids.collect({
        case recomPid if recomPid._2 != pid => recomPid._2
      })
      (pid, pids)
     }
   }) // List((2, List(1, 4, 5)), (1, List(2, 3)))
```

I simplified the input/output form to just focus on getting the collections into the right form.

Comment: Nice but not usable. I need a solution in scalding api.

Answer (score 1):

Assume `pid| recom-pid > temp.txt` and so

```
import scala.io.Source
val xs = Source.fromFile("temp.txt").getLines.toArray.map(_.split("\\|"))
```

We convert `xs` into tuples, like this

```
val pairs = for (Array(pid, recom) <- xs) yield (pid,recom)
Array((1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,2), (2,4), (2,5))
```

and group by the first element,

```
val g = pairs.groupBy(_._1)
Map(2 -> Array((2,1), (2,2), (2,4), (2,5)), 1 -> Array((1,1), (1,2), (1,3)))
```

Then we remove mapped *identity* tuples, which ensures always an entry in the map, where an empty array denotes there was only the identity tuple (viz. unique occurrence of `3|3` would lead to `3 -> Array()`),

```
val res = g.mapValues(_.filter { case (a,b) => a != b } )
Map(2 -> Array((2,1), (2,4), (2,5)), 1 -> Array((1,2), (1,3)))
```

Comment: Nice but not usable. I need a solution in scalding api.

Answer (score 1):

Asssuming your string input is correct that returns you a Map[String, Array[String]]

```
s.split('\n')
.map(_.split("\\|"))
.groupBy(_(0))
.mapValues(_.flatten)
.transform {case (k, v) ⇒ v.filter(_ != k)}
```